# How to create multiple dockable windows?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#, .net, add-in

I am building an add-in and I have several different windows, which I open with the code below. This works fine. However, how can I create the same window n times?

```
    UID dockWinID = new UIDClass();
    dockWinID.Value = ThisAddIn.IDs.MyWindow;

    IDockableWindow dockWindow = ArcMap.DockableWindowManager.GetDockableWindow(dockWinID);

    dockWindow.Show(true);
```

Comment: What's the use case?  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Maybe something similar to attribute table windows? They are dockable. AFAIK, these windows are implemented as [IDataWindow](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//000v00000090000000)s. I wonder if [GenericWindow](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//000v0000001q000000) could help here, though it seems to be (uncomfortably) tied to ActiveX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, all add-in framework types are singletons ([source](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000000zz000000)), meaning they are only intended to exist one at a time. I am not sure but I think the same is also true for [traditional COM dockable windows](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00010000014w000000).

Comment: Yes, the same holds true for the classic IDockableWindowDef implementations.

Comment: Okay. As a workaround I manage the windows by myself with the WindowInteropHelper. I lost all the benefits like docking in ArcMap, but that was never important for me.